# Android XML: How to add White spaces or blank spaces in Unity

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to add blank spaces in my xml so when unity read it the info look decent and nice

**CODE**:

```
 <Record>
        <Row A="Allianz Arena" B="FC Bayern Munich &amp; TSV 1860 München play their home games here"/>
    </Record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&#160;` or `\u0020` encoding for blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If u want space then add "" in start or end of the each line. Use based on your requirement. Thank you.

**Use this below code:**

```
<Record>
        <Row A="Allianz Arena\u0020" 
             B="FC Bayern Munich &amp; TSV 1860 München play their home games here"/>
    </Record>
```